# Rails link_to action with URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, link-to

If I have a route like so

```
get 'controller/:id/action/:param' => 'Controller#action'
```

How can I use `link_to` to create a link like `<a href="/controller/12345/action/abcde">`?

So far I have gotten `link_to 'Link text', {:action => 'action'}`

To give me `<a href="/controller/12345/action">`

but using `link_to 'Link text', {:action => 'action', :param => 'abcde'}`

will give me `<a href="/controller/12345/action?param=abcde">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your route:

```
get 'controller/:id/action/:param' => 'Controller#action', :as => 'custom_show'
```

This should give you a new url helper which you can use like this:

```
<%= link_to "Foobar", custom_show_path(:id=>1234, :param=>'my_param') %>
```

Comment: I've seen the docs for doing this but I can't seem to get it to work... I'm getting `undefined method 'custom_show_path'`

Comment: Does having this route under a resource break this functionality?

Comment: Run `rake routes` and have a look at the output. Maybe you can find it there?

Comment: If it is under a resource it the helper might look different (`myresource_custom_show_path` or `custom_show_myresource_path`). But I'd suggest you move the route outside the resource.