# Rails link_to Non-Resourceful Route with String Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9.3

I'm working on a flight tracking application in Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails (3.2.11). This application has a `Flight` class, which has, among other things, a string column `tail_number` to track the [tail number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration) of the airplane that performed the flight.

I'm attempting to create an index view for the tail number, showing a listing of the tail numbers and the count of each, and linking to a view which will show all `Flights` which have that tail number.  **I have the show page working, but I'm having trouble making `link_to` work on the index page.**

The show view is handled by the `flights` controller's `show_tail` action, which I've set up in routes.rb:

```
match '/tails' => 'flights#index_tails'
match '/tails/:tail_number' => 'flights#show_tail'
```

The flight controller groups the flights by tail number and provides a count:

```
def index_tails
  @flight_tail_numbers = Flight.where("tail_number IS NOT NULL").group("tail_number").count
end
```

On my tail number index page (/app/views/flights/index_tails.html.erb), I create a table of tail numbers and the count of each, intending to have the tail number link to the appropriate show view:

```
<h1>Tail Numbers</h1>

<table>
<% @flight_tail_numbers.each do |tail_number, count| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to(tail_number, tails_path(tail_number)) %></td>
    <td><%= count %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

However, instead of the `link_to` creating a link to /tails/tail_number (for example, `/tails/N909EV`) like I'm hoping, it instead creates a link to /tails.tail_number (`/tails.N909EV`).  This link clearly does not send me to the flights#show_tail that I'm wanting.

I've successfully created indexes for other models that are associated with Flight (Airports, Trips) and and index for Flight itself, and they all work by using, for example, the `link_to trip.name, trip_path(trip)` syntax I'm trying to use for tail numbers.  So this would be pretty trivial if Tail_Number were a model and I can treat it the same way, but it seems far too trivial to be a model versus just an attribute of a given flight.

I'm assuming the reason it's not working for me is that when I'm using `trip_path(trip)`, `trip` is an object whereas in `tails_path(tail_number)`, `tail_number` is a string.  But I'm not sure exactly how I should link to it. I've tried solutions like the named routes in [Rails link_to action with URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782935/rails-link-to-action-with-url-parameters), but I get the same `undefined method` problem if I do that, so I reverted back to what's listed above.

How should I format my link_to to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the action `:show_tail` isn't a RESTful action you'll need to assign it in an `:as` statement.

You can change your route to support what you're trying:

```
match '/tails/:tail_number' => 'flights#show_tail', :as => :tails
```

Which will allow it to match `tails_path`

I'd probably name it something like

```
match '/tails/:tail_number' => 'flights#show_tail', :as => :show_tails
```

and use `show_tails_path(tail_number)` to avoid issues with other actions.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. For some reason, I'd tried renaming the route and linking to that, but never thought to add `_path` to it.